# Android support toolbar title margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

How can I reduce the spacing between actionbar homeasup button and action bar title?

It used to have a smaller spacing but somehow the spacing has increased. I didn't make any changes in the xml or java code that directly relates to the support toolbar.

I tried many things as pointed out in other similar so questions but nothing helped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use this [app:contentInsetLeft](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#attr_android.support.v7.appcompat:contentInsetLeft)
or `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`

Comment: remove `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` and use this attribute `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back_24dp"` and in your activity use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) method

Comment: Thanks again, but still the spacing is same. toolbar.getChildAt(0) gives me the ImageButton, childAt(1) gives me TextView that shows title. Tried settings its layout params, but still no luck. Another thing I noticed when show layout bounds in developer options is that there is no margin shown between back arrow and title text, though it is spaced out a bit. Other elements in the page are showing margins with pink color but these two do not have any margin in-between. What could be the problem?

Comment: How close do you want it to be? There's also `app:titleMarginStart` and `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation `

Comment: Still no change. 
Here is a link to the screenshot of how it is now and how I want it to be
http://i68.tinypic.com/3090axu.png

Comment: it might be because of internal padding of the icon, these attributes definitely work, you can test it by setting them to 100dp for example. your screenshot doesn't work for me

Comment: When I give a positive value it increases the spacing but giving zero doesn't reduce it. I think It currently has marginLeft zero.

Comment: There's no padding in the drawable

Comment: app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
Did the job.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!! It works like a charm, i was looking for different failed workarounds and thi is the only way that worked for me